# Определить гуглбота

Tags: javascript, seo

Здравствуйте более опытные коллеги!

Подскажите, есть ли способ определить гуглбота при обращении к веб - странице?
Нужно для генерации id пользователей, понимаю, что один и тот же пользователь может заходить с разных устройств даже браузеров, это сейчас неважно. Важно не назначать id ботам. Пока придумал способ запись и чтение какого-либо маркера в session storage браузера. Если не получилось вычитать, то это бот =) вот только не знаю есть ли у бота session storage. Может посоветуете более изящное решение.

Comment: Так вроде гулбот не маскируется, и честно [представляется в User-Agent](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=ru)?

Comment: @Yaant, так в том то и сложность, что, вроде, не всегда гуглбот представляется ботом во избежание отличия контента для бота и пользователя.